# SwiftUI state not consistent

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    let countView = CountView()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            countView
            Text("My Count: \(countView.count)")
            Button("Show My Count"){print("\(self.countView.count)")}
        }
    }
}
struct CountView: View {
    @State var count: Int = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Increase count"){self.count += 1}
            Text("Count = \(count)")
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

It happens that `MyCount =` and `Count =` show different value after `count` increased. That always shows `MyCount = 1` no mater what `Count =` is.

Am I doing wrong? How to synchronize `MyCount` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not access another view's `@State`:

```
Text("My Count: \(countView.count)")
```

This is a giant red flag indicating that you are doing something wrong. You need a `@Binding` here.

Instead of making `CountView` "own" the `count`, `ContentView` should own the `count` because it needs to show it in its `Text`. `ContentView` should tell `CountView` to count with `ContentView.count` using a `@Binding`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var count = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CountView(count: $count)
            Text("My Count: \(count)")
            Button("Show My Count"){print("\(self.count)")}
        }
    }
}
struct CountView: View {
    @Binding var count: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Increase count"){self.count += 1}
            Text("Count = \(count)")
        }
    }
}
```